# QGIS atlas by species category

Tags: qgis, atlas

QGIS 3.10.  I have a point dataset of bat records for a county. I want to show a separate page for each species (so multiple records per page) and the geographic extent doesn't change.
This seems more difficult than it ought to be and I feel like I'm missing something?   I've  looked at solutions (on SE & wider web) which are either not similar or are far more complex than this and I haven't been able to adapt these to my requirement.

Comment: create a layer for each bat, and then a map page for each layer and then run the atlas for the areas you want maps of

Comment: Thanks. That's a bit of a workaround ?  It must be possible programmatically but I may have to be pragmatic shortly and fudge it like this or something.

Comment: It may feel like a workaround because the extent isn't changing but that's only one use of the Atlas. The number of pages is based on the number of features in the layer, so if you want five different pages then you need five different features, regardless of the spatial extent. This also lets you add species specific attributes such as "species_name" for use in titles and atlas-based layer filtering.

Comment: Thanks - a species atlas should be just as much a thing as a geographic atlas - I had already made a polygon layer for the extent of 13 stacked rectangles, each with a species attribute and using that is my atlas driver.  I get what you're saying & I was hoping to just aggregate them by attribute (as the Group Stats plugin can) but as a workaround to try and avoid having 13 layers, I've dissolved all the points by species (it's a static dataset for a publication) so that should give me the 13 pages.  I'd also not noticed a hiccup in the name field, which wasn't helping.

Comment: Just investigated, the attribute title "common_name" shows up in full on the table yet is "common_nam" in the expression editor.  I'll make a new short-title field.

Comment: What you want to do is an atlas on aggregated data. Depending on how many time you have a solution create temporary aggregation with toolbox each time. does it match your needs or you have to do it many times a year and need more automatical approach ?